# What are good graphs to compare two sets of data of network delays?

Tags: graphing-functions, statistical-inference, visualization, number-comparison

I have two sets of numbers, each set contains 100 numbers, which are delays that I have measured from a network.

I want to visualize the comparison between these two sets, instead of just provide two "dry" numbers of their mean value. I am thinking of a graph similar to the boxplot, where I can show the mean value, but also display, by some means, the upper and lower limits (for example, the data points whose values fall within the 20% and 80% of the overall value range).

Although I can create such a graph all by myself, I wonder if there is a "classical" graph that is usually used to do this type of comparison. I am an computer engineer and write codes more frequently than do math analysis, so please do not blame me of my limited knowledge of statistics :).

Comment: You could try plotting CDF/CCDFs? Similar to Figs. $8, 9, 10$ in [this](http://people.bu.edu/staro/Characterizing_churn.pdf) paper.

Comment: @an4s, thank you. CDF/CCDF is not very straightforward. I objectgive is just to show the average, and the high-level visual comparison of the datasets.